# What's the pedal spindle size for the NordicTrack GX 4.7 R exercise bike?

Tags: pedals

I am trying to find out pedal spindle size for the NordicTrack GX 4.7 R exercise bike. Is it 1/2 or 9/16?

I want to replace the pedals with larger more substantial ones with a strap.

Thank you!

Comment: I proposed an edit for clarity: basically, put the question in the title. As it is, I thought you were asking about some random elliptical machine and was going to redirect your question.

Answer (score 2):

The [Nordic Track GX 4.7](https://www.ereplacementparts.com/nordictrack-219141-bike-parts-c-147683_148255_294246.html?) comes with a [three piece crank](https://www.ereplacementparts.com/right-crank-arm-p-891328.html) so it has 9/16 pedals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

9/16" is most likely but not 100% certain.